# Solr enable external user to query database but no access to dashboard

Tags: python, macos, solr

I configured a Solr server (Solr version 9.2) on my machine (Mac OS) and to enter to the dashboard page it requires some credentials.
I successfully created a core and load a json file in it with my database.
Now I would like to allow external users without any credential to query the database, but in Python every time I use "requests.get(link_to_solr_with_query)" I get get a 401 response.
How can I do it?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Generally you should _not_ let external clients access your Solr instance unless you're sure about what you're doing. It's usually far better to have a small service between the internet and the Solr instance, making sure that you only issue the queries/handler/etc. that you want to expose. However, authentication etc. in Solr is detailed in the reference manual: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/securing-solr.html

Comment: Simply build a small middleware via flask REST etc.